# Angular wont display Array Description properly

Tags: html, .net, angular

Im working on a .net core mvc project with angular frontend.
When im trying to display the description of a parameter, the arrays wont show it. Single parameters do, thou it just wont appear when there is an array.
How can i fix this?

```
    <h3>Call Succeded</h3>
    <div *ngIf="serviceMethodInformationOutput && serviceMethodInformationOutput.serviceObject && serviceMethodInformationOutput.serviceObject.childServiceObjectParameter">
      <h4>Properties:</h4>
      <div *ngFor="let parameter of serviceMethodInformationOutput.serviceObject.childServiceObjectParameter">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px">
          <div class="col-md-6" style="font-weight:bold">{{parameter.name}}:</div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <br />
            <ng-container *ngIf="parameter.isArray; else description">{{parameter.description}}</ng-container>
            <ng-template #description>{{parameter.description}}</ng-template>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!postServicesQueryResponseArray || postServicesQueryResponseArray.length == 0">
```

[image: This is for one of the Services, where it doesnt display the description on Groups]

The Service Description is from a ServiceObjectModel that is in another Project. It has a Class called CreateServiceObjectModel, which has a param called description. This String is then read here and not put in correctly.
Here the CreateServiceObjectModel:

```
public class CreateServiceObjectModel
{
    public CreateServiceObjectModel(string? name, string? type, string? description, bool isArray, bool isOptional = false)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Description = description;
        IsArray = isArray;
        IsOptional = isOptional;
    }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Type { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsOptional { get; set; }

    public bool IsArray { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Return json Array from API. Assign it  to array in ts file and show it. I think your api is not returning array of descriptions.  @DennisM

Answer (score 1):

Return json Array from API. Assign it to array in ts file and show it. I think your api is not returning array of descriptions. @DennisM

your api should return something like this :{

```
"compnay":"google",
"id":30,
"description":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]
}
```

using httpclinet in angualr u call the api and create a class in the component to parse the response.